# How to show dynamic component in Angular Ionic Modal

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

In an Angular **Ionic** app I want to show a **modal** presenting content from a **dynamic loaded component**.

I'm using `ion-modal` tag, but since it uses `ng-template` tag to present content, I'm not able to access the host container inside it:

This is a [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-wmzmvn?file=src/app/app.component.ts) showing the non working code.

Here you can see my host div inside the ng-template:

```html
  <ion-modal [trigger]="'open-modal-2'">
    <ion-content [scrollY]="false">
      <ng-template>
        <div #myHost></div> <!-- host inside ng-template! -->
      </ng-template>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal>
```

When I try to access myHost, it is `undefined` (even using AfterViewInit):

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 @ViewChild('myHost', { static: false, read: ViewContainerRef }) myHost;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.myHost); // undefined
    const componentRef = this.myHost.createComponent(HelloComponent);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arrived to the conclusion that for this case it's necessary to use Ionic `ModalController` instead of `ion-modal`. See [Controller Modals](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#controller-modals).

This is the working [Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-6ac7wn?file=src/app/app.component.html).

`app.component.ts` Inject ModalController service and create method for presenting the modal:

```js
...
export class AppComponent {
  name: string = '';

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  async openModal() {
    const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: CustomComponent,
    });
    modal.present();

    const { data, role } = await modal.onWillDismiss();

    if (role === 'confirm') {
      this.name = data;
    }
  }
}
```

`app.component.html` Assign click event to the method:

```html
<ion-app>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item [button]="true" (click)="openModal()">
        <ion-label>ControllerModal Modal</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <h1>Hello {{ name }}</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

`custom.component.ts` Create the component that will be inserted in the modal; it also injects ModalController so it can dismiss:

```js
...
export class CustomComponent implements OnInit {
  name: string;

  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  cancel() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss(null, 'cancel');
  }

  confirm() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss(this.name, 'confirm');
  }
}
```

`custom.component.html` Just a simple form with two buttons:

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button color="medium" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Welcome</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-button (click)="confirm()">Confirm</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content class="ion-padding">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Your name</ion-label>
    <ion-input [(ngModel)]="name" placeholder="Your name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```